# prolog: rule to check pythagorean triplet?

Tags: math, prolog, pythagorean

Prolog Keeps saying ['no'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOdjCb4LwQY) to me.... :(

I am *very* new to prolog, I have a basic question:

So I'm trying to produce a simple rule that checks if three numbers constitute the length of the sides of a right-angle triangle, like this:

```
addup(X,Y,Z) :- X is Y+Z. /* this works*/
pythag(H,A,B) :- (H*H) is (A*A) + (B*B). /*this doesn't work*/
```

For testing, the 'addup' rule DOES appear to work....
I believe there is an issue with the left-hand side of the 'IS' in my program, as the following test seems to indicate this:

In interactive mode I can as whether 2 is the sum of 1 and 1, and it says yes:

```
| ?- 2 is 1+1.

yes
```

But if I switch the left and right hand sides; it says no:

```
| ?- 1+1 is 2.

no
```

Can somebody provide a correct version of the pythag rule above ?
Version Info follows:

```
GNU Prolog 1.3.0
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2007 Daniel Diaz
| ?-
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My prolog knowledge is old, but I believe the problem is that Prolog only evaluates the right side of an `is`

So try:

```
pythag(H,A,B) :- Z is H*H, Z is (A*A) + (B*B).
```